# Css scale text still blurry after searching on StackOverflow

Tags: css, text, rendering, transform, blur

URL: https://www.royalsmushicafe.dk/

I have issues with the left side menu text looking blurry on mouseover. It's as if it's blurry during the animation and turns crisp again only after the animation is over. In Safari it stays blurry.

I'm using `Transform: scale(1.2)` and `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;`, but have tried quite a lot of suggested solutions.

I've been browsing StackOverflow and Google without luck, with suggestions like using transform `perspective(1px)`, `scale3d`, `translate3d( 0, 0, 0)`, `backface-visibility: hidden` even `filter: blur(0)` and whatnot – nothing has resulted in the expected behaviour of a crisp text scaling on mouseover :(

*Any help would be much appreciated*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just had almost the exact same problem, and found all the same hack ideas for `perspective(1px)`, `backface-visibility: hidden`, and so on, with no success. Chrome and Firefox are fine, but scaled-up text blurs horribly in Safari. For anyone else experiencing this, the band-aid solution is to scale *down* instead of up.

In my case, I have a label that moves and changes scale when the input has content:

```
label {
  will-change: transform, color;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform-origin: top left;
  height: 20px;
}

input:placeholder-shown:not(:focus) + label {
  transform: translate3d(0,.6rem,0) scale3d(1.5,1.5,1);
}
```

<sup>Idea here is that the label has the same styles if the input is focused or has content, and is bigger if the input is empty and unfocused (hence the funky pseudoclass selector.)</sup>

The problem is that using `transform` like this triggers GPU compositing on the `<label>`. When this happens, the composited layer is rendered *like a bitmap* in the GPU, at the dimensions calculated during CSS layout (20px here). Then, **the GPU layer is scaled up** (in this case by 1.5x, so it's now 30px high, and blurry).

Chrome and Firefox seem to re-render the layer at final scale which un-blurs it. Safari does not, probably to save memory since the composited layer is dimensionally smaller (20px high instead of 30px).

To make it work better, I opted to scale down:

```
label {
  will-change: transform, color;
  /* reverse the scaling ratio */
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(0.67, 0.67, 1);
  transform-origin: top left;
  height: 20px;
}

input:placeholder-shown:not(:focus) + label {
  /* reset to scale of 1 */
  transform: translate3d(0,.6rem,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
}
```

The scaled-down text is a tiny bit blurry, but much less noticeably. I might try different `-webkit-font-smoothing` values, although I don't hold out a lot of hope because of the way GPU rendering works. Scaling ratios that resolve to a clean, integer pixel font size will probably work better, too.

Answer (score -1):

Would backface-visibility: hidden; help? I recall having similar problems and it did help.

Comment: You can always make the animation time shorter - it wouldn't be so noticable then. I know it's not a solution to your problem, but...

Comment: Still no answer to this? :(
Is it not possible?

Comment: The only other thing that _kinda_ seems to work is if you'd change font-size instead of transform: scale. From what I've tried, though, you'd have to adjust the font size at least by 4px for the animation to look smoothly. You might also try to reduce letter-spacing (by setting it to negative values) so that the text won't grow so much. https://codepen.io/Kampo/pen/EpmeZe

Comment: Yes thank you, I tried this as well, but it appears to be stuttering quite a lot :(